# Why is there no /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_thresh

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, vmware

and, more importantly, how can I adjust this threshold for Ubuntu 14.04 server installations?

I have standard Ubuntu 14.04 server VMs crashing due to CPU softlocks and [VMWare recommends](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1009996) adjusting this threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new(er) kernel, you tune `/proc/sys/kernel/watchdog_thresh` instead.
(Older kernels use `/proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_thresh`, I think).

I add the following line to end of /etc/sysctl.conf to have it applied at boot:

```
kernel.watchdog_thresh=nn
```

where nn is a number 0 or higher.

Comment: It'd be interesting up to which kernel version `/proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_thresh` is used.

Comment: Not sure, but it's been gone for at least 2 years now:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/0TENQU5rF1U